# Tag question with "Not only . . . but also"

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

In case of "Not only . . . but also", the verb agrees with the second subject :

> Not only he but also **I** *am* intelligent.

Can we use a tag question with this sentence?

> Not only he but also *I am* intelligent, *aren't I?*
>   Or,
>   Not only is he intelligent but also I am, *aren't I?*

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence reads oddly to me. I would say:

Not only is he intelligent, but I am too.

For the same reason, I don't like your first question. The second one seems to be grammatical, but I can't imagine anyone using it in ordinary conversation. It would be more natural to say:

He's intelligent, and I am too, aren't I?

Comment: Or (second sentence) "He's intelligent but so am I, aren't I."

Comment: Why 'but'? I think it should be *'and so am I'* .